# How can I affect the default sort order in social pane?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I need to customize the way that social pane displays things. The first task is to set the default sort order to be by date. Is it possible at all?

I've also noticed that the social pane in leads gives other results than the one in contacts. The latter seems to be richer on appointments (I've made the same number of appointments for a lead as for a contact, of course). Is that me being confused or is that an intended behavior?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The social pane is not customizable.

Someone in the Dynamics CRM Facebook Group tried to start an opensource project to offer an alternative to the social pane, but as far as I know it didn't start yet.

Comment: Being stubborn as a donkey, I wonder if there's an dirty work-around. If we'd obtain a reference to the DOM object on the page and then play around with the actual HTML elements there? Do you see any issues with that (except that it slightly unsupported - with a very forgiving definition of "slightly" - and that it'd be a PIA to create the references to the actual elements)?

Comment: "you can play with the DOM until the customer pays" :)

Comment: I'm interpreting your comment as "*one **can** do that*" as in "*one **can** poke one's left eye out*". But one would surely **not want** to do so.   :)

Comment: If you are interested in playing around with the social pane object this article which gives a jscript example for hiding social pane tabs might give you a starting point.     http://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/hide-postsactivitiesnotes-from-social-pane-crm-2013/